# Progress blockage due to political tensions

Tags: communication, politics

I am close to issuing an internal compliance report on the internal processes at the company where I work as part of a quality review. During testing, some process weaknesses were found for which I documented. I have discussed with appropriate parties.**My main problem has being the the inability to obtain a response** A response can include acceptance of the result or remediation going forward.

I sense the reason may be political as it is uncomfortable for management to be confronted with weaknesses in work they is responsible for. I am a junior in my team. As a result of the non - cooperation / non - response, I am unable to issue an clean opinion and might be forced to issue a adverse finding, [per due diligence and professional care standards.](http://www.aicpa.org/Research/Standards/AuditAttest/DownloadableDocuments/AU-00230.pdf)

I would rather not issue a adverse opinion and possibly create friction..

**How can I discuss this with my manager and limit damage?**

**As I have received nothing but a stone wall, is there other steps I can take to encourage a response / cooperation?**

Comment: Why haven't you sent basically exactly this to your manager already?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

This isn't your problem, it's your managers problem, give him/her all the facts impartially as you see them and then it's up to them to do their job. A follow up request from your manager is a lot harder to ignore than one from you.

Just do your job properly, don't worry about friction, it will just impact badly on your ability to do your work.

There is often a desire in these situations to give those at fault a heads up to help them out, but if they decline it, it's their funeral, don't get yourself involved, it could backfire.

Answer (score 5):

Ignore the questions of why. Just give your manager the facts: "I'm almost done, but I can't seem to get a response from Fred. Should I finish without his response, or can you suggest some way to shake this loose? I understand it's probably not his top priority, but..."